# Cannot use cordova vibrate plugin with ionic with ios

Tags: cordova, plugins, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, vibration

Testing in Safari, I am receiving this error:
**undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.notification.vibrate')**

Error in the simulator or device:
**WARNING:  998: Failure to setup sound, err = -50**

I have added the plugin to my project, confirmed by attempting to add it again. I receive message "already added.."

Thanks,
Wayne

Comment: Try once to remove platform and then add again platform and plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try using Ionic-Native to wrap the Cordova Vibration Plugin. You'll still want to remove it and re-add it:

```
ionic plugin remove cordova-plugin-vibration --save
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-vibration --save
bower install ionic-native --save
ionic prepare ios
```

Once you've done that, you'll need to do the following:

1. Reference the `ionic.native.js` script from your bower folder.
2. Make sure your module relies on `'ionic.native'`.
3. Inject the `$cordovaVibration` service into your controller.
4. Call `$cordovaVibration.vibrate(100)` from your controller.

You mentioned you're testing in Safari. Do you mean that you're using `ionic serve` and you see these errors? Or are you using Safari to debug on a real device? If you're just in the browser, I don't believe that will ever work. When I try it in Safari, I get this error when I try to call the vibrate function.

```
Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'b.get(window,e.pluginRef)[n].apply')
r@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/ionic-native/ionic.native.min.js:4:18863
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/ionic-native/ionic.native.min.js:4:22713
value@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/ionic-native/ionic.native.min.js:4:21241
vibrate@http://localhost:3000/main/debug/debug-ctrl.js:55:17
fn
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/ionic/js/ionic-angular.js:12249:21
$eval@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:17682:28
$apply@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:17782:30
http://localhost:3000/bower_components/ionic/js/ionic-angular.js:12248:19
defaultHandlerWrapper@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3497:15
eventHandler@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3485:23
dispatchEvent@[native code]
triggerMouseEvent@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/ionic/js/ionic.js:2946:20
tapClick@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/ionic/js/ionic.js:2935:20
tapMouseUp@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/ionic/js/ionic.js:3011:13
```

In both Safari and Chrome, Ionic-Native provides a very handy warning message:

```
Native: tried accessing the e plugin but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
```

Comment: Thanks MikeC! I will give this a shot and let you know how it goes.